# Is this a secure method of escaping a SQL query parameter?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, security

At my work it used to be tradition to form SQL queries by unsafely concatenating parameters into the query strings. This leads, of course, to SQL injection vulnaribilities. This wasn't considered a huge issue because all of the Java software in which this happens runs on closed networks of which all users are assumed to be trusted. Also, the queries are executed from client-side applications with database access, so a user could technically execute malicious queries anyway.

Nonetheless, it's planned to support prepared statements in the new version of the database layer. In the meantime, I've written a small library on top of the existing database layer (which only supports executing a query from a SQL String, without the option for prepared statements or parameter escaping) that allows writing safe parameterized queries by escaping string parameters.

As part of this library, I've wrote the following method that escapes a String literal. I escape the same characters as PHP's addslashes function, but I try to avoid its multibyte character vulnerability by detecting supplementary (32-bit) characters:

```
private String escapeString(String str)
{
    List<Character> toEscape = Arrays.asList('\'', '"', '\\', '\0');

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if(i < str.length() - 1 && c >= '\uD800' && c <= '\uDBFF')
        {
            char next = str.charAt(i + 1);

            if(next >= '\uDC00' && next <= '\uDFFF')
            {
                // Two-char supplementary character. Escape neither.
                result.append(c);
                result.append(next);
                ++i;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if(toEscape.contains(c))
        {
            // Special character. Add escaping \.
            result.append('\\');
        }

        // Copy character itself.
        result.append(c);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

My question is whether this method of escaping queries is secure enough (and I didn't oversee anything or made an implementation mistake). It can be assumed the input String is valid UTF-16. The DBMS's this will be used with are MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: The character set / encoding used in the database connection and the database tables is important too, as problems can be introduced when "translating" characters between schemes. If you can ensure they are always the same as Java's native representation, you might reduce the attack surface.

Comment: Don't even bother: [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com) is full of examples where strings are poorly escaped. Rather go the parameterized query route as soon as possible. Besides, it won't be that difficult to change your code.
See also [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: Its not just sql injection you need to worry about. Without using bind variables (on Oracle, anyway) your sql cache will be wasted as you continuously hard parse each "new" statement.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware parameterized SQL is highly preferable. However, this is a temporary measure that is build on top of the existing database layer that can be used until said layer (which does not support parameterized queries) is updated.

Answer (score 4):

Without an ORM, prepared statements or stored procedures I'd be cautious of any string SQL sanitization routine.

Comment: Stored procedure pose a risk of their own.  If they are poorly written you can have the same effect as java sql injection.

Comment: @tom care to elaborate what you mean by "poorly written"? Unless the procedure creates a SQL statement dynamically by concatenating user-supplied values, I tend to disagree.

Comment: @Frank you are pointing out exactly what I mean.  I have seen stored procedure that build the select by concatenating elements and then using an `execute immediate`.  The correct way would obviously be using bind variables (or not using an `execute immediate`at all) but junior developers don't always do that.  Hence the need for code reviews!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let's say you have an integer field which they input a PIN into:

"SELECT columns FROM table WHERE PIN = " + sanitizedstring

and then for input you type in:
1234 OR 1 = 1

And now your "pin" always is accepted, without any funny characters being used.

This could work for fields besides ints too (since yes, you could validate that an int input is actually an int before handing it over to the SQL.)

Comment: The method I posted is not intended to be used directly by the library user. It is used internally to handle to escaping of String types (I handle integers differently). The library's visible API is more similar to that of PHP's PDO.